# How do you translate expressions like "The General is only as good as the soldiers that he commands"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

There is an expression in English in the form "The [blank] is only as good as the [blank]".  An example below is

> The general is only as good as the soldiers that he commands.

What is the proper French construction for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Le général n'est pas meilleur que les soldats qu'il commande.*, I think. It's not literal translation, but it's French usage.

Literal translation should be “*Le général est seulement aussi bon que ses soldats*”, but it doesn't work in French, I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

> Le général *ne vaut pas mieux que* ses soldats, 
>   *AJOUT* : le général *n'est pas meilleur que* ses soldats

**Ne pas valoir mieux que/ne pas être meilleur que**  pour rendre **only as good as**  organise les entités selon leur valeur personnelle ..
.. et non selon leur rang social, ou l'idée que l'on se fait en jugeant sur les apparences.

Il faut toutefois préciser que *ne pas valoir mieux que* ou *ne pas être meilleur que* employé seul est très péjoratif.
Dans l'exemple, on pourrait sous-entendre que toute l'armée est soit corrompue, soit incapable.

> La valeur d'un général dépend de celle de ses soldats.

est beaucoup plus proche, dans le sens qu'une positivité ne peut être seule, mais s'établit en relation avec d'autres positivités
**dépendre de** indique alors que **only as good as** relativise les valeurs mises en jeu en marquant les interactions.

Si le contexte est plus générique, et la critique plus générale :

> Le mieux est l'ennemi du bien.

permet d'apporter une sentence (d'apparence) définitive en conclusion d'un exposé sur une organisation hiérarchique quelconque qui peut évoluer selon le [Principe de Peter](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principe_de_Peter)

Comment: Utiliser _bien_ ou _mieux_ plutôt que _bon_ ou _meilleur_ pour traduire _good_ dans ce contexte me semble faire un contresens.

Answer (score 3):

A translation could be:

> La solidité d'une chaîne dépend de son maillon le plus faible.

Comment: Not really a translation for "as good as", but it's well related with the idea.

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation would be

- Le général n'est qu'aussi bon que les soldats qu'il commande.

but I would probably use something like

- Un général ne vaut que par les soldats qu'il commande.
- Un général ne vaut que ce que valent les soldats qu'il commande.